# access denied with mysql database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, silverstripe, modx-revolution

I want to install a CMS, first time I tried to install "Silver Stripe CMS" but the installation hangs at the database it shows me this error:
I couldn't find a database server on 'localhost': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Then I tried to install the CMS "Modx" still hangs at the database the message this time is:
Connexion au serveur MySQL:
No processor specified!

I tried to reinstall PhpMyAdmin, I affice this error:

> Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création de la base de données.
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)
>
> Vous pouvez soit recommencer soit abandonner l'opération. Si vous
>   choisissez « Recommencer », la mise à jour sera tentée à nouveau en
>   vous       posant à nouveau les questions de configuration. Avec
>   l'option                 « Recommencer avec les mêmes réglages », la
>   mise à jour sera tentée            immédiatement. Avec le choix
>   « Abandonner », la mise à jour échouera et        vous devrez revenir
>   à la version précédente, désinstaller et
>   reconfigurer ce paquet, à moins d'effectuer vous-même les opérations
>   nécessaires pour continuer à l'utiliser. Enfin, le choix « Ignorer »
>   poursuivra les opérations en ignorant les erreurs ultérieures issues
>   de        dbconfig-common.
>
> ```
> <Ok>
> ```

Although I connect well with my phpmyadmin login as root and my password no problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the giveaway is in this bit:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

It looks as if the password isn't set for your CMS that you have installed. I am not familiar with silverstripe, but it seems that you will need to edit a file somewhere to tell it the password.

Also, using the `root` user is probably not advisable, I would suggest creating a secondary user on your database with the permissions you want and use that account in the CMS.

Comment: He has two contradicting mentions of `using password`, one with `YES` and the other with `NO` so I'm not sure your answer is relevant to his case. Anyways, +1 for the last sentence!

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect from command-line, if you're logged in as `root` simply type `mysql` and enter. if it works, the problem is on the application level.

Look for silver-stripe configuration file:
`<your app root folder>/conf/ConfigureFromEnv.php`

and make sure to set the credentials right, in lines:

```
/* Database connection */
define('SS_DATABASE_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('SS_DATABASE_USERNAME', 'root');
define('SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD', '');
```

I agree with my friend Fluffeh, you should not use `root` - better create a dedicated user for Silver Stripe.